# How do I use the command New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Can someone help define how I use New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment?

The MS doc is, well lets say a little confusing!
Essentially I want to assign the application administrator role to a registered application. Is this even the correct cmdlet?

Thanks

/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some more detail about this in the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rbacapplication-post-roleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell)

| Parameter | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| roleDefinitionId | String | Identifier of the role definition the assignment is for. |
| principalId | String | The identifier of the principal to which the assignment is granted. |
| directoryScopeId | String | Identifier of the directory object representing the scope of the assignment. Either this property or **appScopeId** is required. The scope of an assignment determines the set of resources for which the principal has been granted access. Directory scopes are shared scopes stored in the directory that are understood by multiple applications. Use `/` for tenant-wide scope. Use **appScopeId** to limit the scope to an application only. |
| appScopeId | String | Identifier of the app-specific scope when the assignment scope is app-specific. Either this property or **directoryScopeId** is required. App scopes are scopes that are defined and understood by this application only. Use `/` for tenant-wide app scopes. Use **directoryScopeId** to limit the scope to particular directory objects, for example, administrative units. |

#### Example to assign `Global Administrator` role to an Enterprise Application

```
$roleDefinitionId = (Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Global Administrator'").Id
$appObjectId = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'AppName'").Id

New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment -PrincipalId $appObjectId -RoleDefinitionId $roleDefinitionId -DirectoryScopeId "/"
```

#### Note

From your use-case, you can also use the cmdlet [New-MgDirectoryRoleMemberByRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/new-mgdirectoryrolememberbyref?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

```
# Get the role Id
$roleId = (Get-MgDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Global Administrator'").Id

# Get the object ID of your Enterprise Application
$appObjectId = (Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'AppName'").Id

$body = @{
    "@odata.id"= "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{$($appObjectId)}"
}

New-MgDirectoryRoleMemberByRef -DirectoryRoleId $roleId -BodyParameter $body
```

Comment: Problem I'm having now is:

Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition_List1: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

How do I add the required scope to allow myself to perform the action?

Comment: I managed to obtain the scopes needed. That was a silly mistake on my part! What I still need to do is ensure that the application which has the permissions of Application Administrator can only 'act on' another application. So if I connect using App3 (which thanks to you has the role of App Admin) by using a self signed cert, I want that app to assign users to a separate and single App (App2). Can this be done?

Comment: @AndrewStevens In this scenario, you can use `New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleAssignment` as in my example, with the Enterprise Application object ID of App2 in the `DirectoryScopeId` parameter, e.g. `-DirectoryScopeId "/3c9c7bb9-28a2-458d-a6df-426fe4022251"`. Note the leading slash before the GUID